# CGAL - how to use CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::connected_components to convert one CGAL::Surface_mesh into many?

Tags: c++, c, graph, mesh, cgal

I am creating a mesh utility library, and one of the functionalities that I would like to include is the ability to break apart disjoint partitions of a mesh. To that end, I am trying to write a method that takes in a `CGAL::Surface_mesh` and returns a `std::vector<CGAL::Surface_mesh>`, where each element is a connected component of the input mesh.

I see that CGAL has [`CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::connected components`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__keep__connected__components__grp.html#gabe2052b2281e1e628e68d8fea94be2d9) function, but that just seems to assign a label to each face indicating which component it's a part of. How can I use the result of that operation to construct a new `CGAL::Surface_mesh` from every group of faces with the same label?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use the result of `connected_components()` as input parameter for [the Face_filtered_graph](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/structCGAL_1_1Face__filtered__graph.html#abf094836eb5948d27c204c776708cce9). 
You can do something like that I believe:

```
 FCCmap fccmap = mesh.add_property_map<face_descriptor, faces_size_type> 
                 ("f:CC").first;
 faces_size_type num = PMP::connected_components(mesh,fccmap); 
 std::vector<Mesh> meshes(num);
 for(int i=0; i< num; ++i)
 {
   Filtered_graph ffg(mesh, i, fccmap);
   CGAL::copy_face_graph(ffg, meshes[i]);
 }
```